# Accessing parameters from nodeJS/ExpressJS sent from html form by POST Method

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I would like to know the command to access parameters sent through post method from HTML Forms

I have tried all these but they print `undefined` or sends back an `error` ...

**EDIT 1:** Forgot to mention, I have also added this `server.use(express.bodyParser());`

**EDIT 2:**

```
var express = require('express'),
server  = express(),
client  = require('mysql').createConnection({ host:'localhost', user:'root', password:'password' });
```

using dbCRUD for rest services in MySQL

```
var dbcrud  = require('dbcrud').init(client, 'contacts', model);
```

then I do a

```
server.use(express.bodyParser());
```

the post functionality is carried out here..

```
server.post('/families',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.id);
    console.log("1: " + req.param.id);
    console.log("2: " + req.params.id);
    console.log("3: " + req.param("id"));
    console.log("4: " + req.params('id'));
    console.log("5: " + req.params[0]);
    console.log("6: " + req.body.name);
    console.log("7: " + req.body.notes);
    console.log("8: " + req.body.id);
    //console.log("5: " + req.params[0]);
    res.send('Hello POST : families');
});
```

I add the routes here...

```
dbcrud.addRoutes(server);
```

In HTML Form i have specified the id and name attributes for the input tag ...

```
<form method="post" action="http://10.180.218.72:3000/families">
   id    : <input type="number" id="id" name="id"></input>
   name  : <input type="text" id="name" name="name"></input>
   notes : <input type="text" id="notes" name="notes"></input>
           <input type="submit" value = "submit" ></input>
</form>
```

Comment: can you post more of your code? or at least the order middleware, route and app.listen appear in your code?

Comment: edited, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try `app.use(express.bodyParser());` in your code. bodyParser is a express middleware for parsing body of post request.

Comment: Also add enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to your form html code

Comment: Put `app.use(express.bodyParser())` *before* any of your routes.